# Training and fine tuning MBart on a specefic (unsupported yet) language

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, machine-translation

I would like to train Hugging face MBart model to be able to translate between Hungarian and English or any other unsupported language (it currently supports 25 languages ).
I have read the original documentation and a [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-train) on how to train a language model on their website but I am not sure how translate that to what I want to do or if that is of any benefit in the first place. I would appreciate any idea or reference.